# How do I show a picture in pygame?

Tags: python, image, pygame

I am wondering how to show a picture in pygame. This is what I have tried so far

```
house = pygame.image.load('house.png')
```

Is this how you define of the picture and do I have to call on it later in the code or do I just do this line of code? If anyone could help that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: you have to `blit()` it to buffer and later you have to `flip()` or `update()` to display buffer. You should have it in any tutorial. BTW: and don't forget to get events from system because on some systems PyGame may not work if it doesn't get mouse/key events from system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimal working example but you should see it in any tutorial.

First you have to send image to buffer (which represents screen/window surface)

```
screen.blit(image, (0, 0))  # draw in buffer
```

and later you send buffer on screen/window (after you draw all elements in buffer)

```
pygame.display.flip() # send buffer on screen
```

PyGame uses [double buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics) to prevent [image flickering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_(screen))

For single static image you could do it before `mainloop` but normally it is used inside `mailoop` so in every loop you can change image or other elements to make animation.

```
#import sys
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
FPS = 25 # frames per seconds

# --- classes --- (CamelCaseNames)

# empty

# --- functions --- (lower_case_names)

# empty

# --- main --- (lower_case_names)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )

image = pygame.image.load('image.jpg') #.convert()

# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # exit on clicking button [X]
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: # exit on pressing ESC
                running = False

    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill(BLACK) # clear screen
    screen.blit(image, (0, 0)) # draw in buffer
    pygame.display.flip() # send buffer on screen

    # --- FPS ---

    clock.tick(FPS) # slow down to 25 FPS

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
#sys.quit()
```